# jQuery extend method with parameter?

Tags: jquery, html, extend

Using the following jQuery:

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
    resizelis: function(xWidth) {
      var mButtons = this.length;
      var buttonSize = (xWidth / mButtons);
        return this.each(function() {
            this.css("width", buttonSize + "px");
            this.children("a").css("width", buttonSize + "px");
        });
    }
});
```

And I use the method like so:

```
var $width = $window.scrolltop() > $("#header_image").outerHeight() ? .92 * $(window).width() : .92 * $(".content").width();
$(".menu").children("li").resizelis($width);
```

HTML

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li class="current"><a accesskey="1" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a accesskey="2" href="highlights.html">Highlights</a></li>
    <li><a accesskey="3" href="agenda.html">Agenda</a></li>
    <li><a accesskey="4" href="tracks.html">Tracks</a></li>
    <li><a accesskey="5" href="sponsors.html">Sponsors / Exhibits</a></li>
    <li><a accesskey="6" href="travel.html">Travel</a></li>
    <li><a accesskey="7" href="register.html">Register</a></li>
</ul>
```

But this gives me an error.  What am I doing wrong exactly?  Thanks.

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: `Uncaught exception: TypeError: '$(".menu").children("li").resizelis' is not a function`  This happens whether or not I put the code inside `$(document).ready()` or not.

Comment: is `$window` a variable that you previously declared? You use it like that when you declare `$width`. Did you mean `$(window)`?

Comment: Yes, `var $window = $(window);` is previously declared.

Comment: Then you shouldn't use `$(window)` later on in the same line :p

Comment: Are you sure to declare `resizelis` method before using it?

Comment: @Archer - True, but that doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: I think you'll find that @A.Wolff is correct, and that the function is not defined when you try to use it, as the error message says.  Move the function declaration to the very top of your script, before everything else and see how that goes.

Comment: @Archer, yes, I have just done this.  It still doesn't work.

Comment: @A.Wolff I don't mean before any other script tags - just before any other script (that he may have in his page) :)

Comment: @Archer ya, i just reread your comment and get what you mean now :)

Comment: @SolomonClosson do you have an online page we can see or can you copy your entire code in a pastebin?

Comment: You declare the function inside `document.ready()` ???  Also, the only errors I see are ones that are answered below about using `$(this)` instead of `this`.

Comment: @Archer - I have tried both, inside and outside of `$(document).ready()`, neither one works.  I just took it outside of the `$(document).ready()` and you can see it still doesn't work.

Comment: There's still bugs in the script.  See the answer by @HanletEscaño below.  If I run this on your page `$(".menu").children("li").resizelis(500)` it resizes the navigation and I get no errors.  It's the other errors that are causing your problems.

Comment: Thanks, yeah, I realize that needed to change `scrolltop` to `scrollTop` instead.  CHEERS!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upon debugging your code, I found that within the extend method you use `this` instead of `$(this)`, and you try to use the css method with `this`, which is not a jQuery object. Try changing `this` to `$(this)`, and try again:

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
    resizelis: function(xWidth) {
      var mButtons = this.length; //same as with the jquery object $(this)
      var buttonSize = (xWidth / mButtons);
        return $(this).each(function() 
       {
            $(this).css("width", buttonSize + "px");
            $(this).children("a").css("width", buttonSize + "px");
        });
    }
});
```

Inside the `each` loop, `this` is a `HTMLLIElement`, to use the css method, use `$(this)`.

Comment: Even though it is true, that will not solve the OP's problems. OP can't access the function...

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon, yes, but this causes a javascript exception, thus breaking the code and causing it not to work.

Comment: Why does jQuery use it for their example use of `jQuery.fn.extend` than? in the `this.each` part  http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.fn.extend/

Comment: @SolomonClosson in that example is ok because they are not using any jquery method on the element, but you are.

Comment: @SolomonClosson this.checked is a native Javascript attribute, not a jQuery function.

Comment: What about `this.each`??

Comment: That one would work fine because `this` in that context is the argument you pass, which is already a jquery object.

Comment: Updated questions with link to online example.

Comment: @SolomonClosson you are getting `Object #<HTMLLIElement> has no method 'css'`, which is the error I talk about above. change `this` to `$(this)` inside the `.each` and that particular error should go away.

Comment: Ok, so just changed to use `$(this)` and problem still exists.  It is not working.

Comment: Now you are getting another error. `Object [object Object] has no method 'scrolltop'` Change `scrolltop` to `scrollTop` with uppercase T

Comment: Ha, thanks a million, this is working now.  Yeah, there's a ton of stuff going on.  Suppose I needed to use `$(this)`.  THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Comment: Yeah, me too!!  I was starting to pull out my hair again...lol